# how to get dict of model objects keyed by field

Tags: python, django, model

Assuming I have Django model called 'Blog' with a primary key field 'id', is there a query I can run that will return a dictionary with keys of the id values indexing the Blog model instances?

in_bulk() seems like the kind of thing I want, but it requires a list of the specific id values in this case, e.g.

```
Blog.objects.in_bulk([1])
```

will give

```
{1: <Blog: Beatles Blog>}
```

The document says that if you pass an empty list you'll get an empty dictionary back, so is there any way I can get *all* values back?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's just python

```
{x.pk:x for x in Blog.objects.all()}
```

EDIT:

Alb here, just adding that if you're using Python 2.6 or earlier you need to use this older style syntax:

```
dict((x.pk, x) for x in Blog.objects.all())
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm fairly new to python, what's the name of this feature so I can read more about it?

Comment: @Alb the {x.pk: x for x in  ...} is call dictionary comprehension. the Blog.objects.all() is a django query to get all the rows

Comment: @Alb take a look at http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries the very end of paragraph

Comment: @DmitryShevchenko Thanks, got caught out for a minute, as I was using python 2.6, I've edited your answer to give the solution for that too. Thanks again.

Comment: @DmitryShevchenko There's a profound reminder in "It's just python" to avoid limiting oneself to a framework's API. Sometimes it's easy to get lost in the Django docs and overlook a standard Python solution.

Answer (score 16):

The `id_list` parameter of the [in_bulk](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#in-bulk) method is `None` by default, so just don't pass anything to it:

```
>>> Blog.objects.in_bulk()
{1: <Blog: Beatles Blog>, 2: <Blog: Cheddar Talk>, 3: <Blog: Django Weblog>}
```

In the result, the default key is the primary key. To override that use:

```
Blog.objects.in_bulk(field_name='<unique_field_name>')
```

NOTE: the key must be unique or you will get `ValueError`

Comment: FYI `field_name` is available in Django >=2.0 only https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/2.0/#models

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to put ValuesListQuerySet object in to "in_bulk" method like this:

```
blog_query = Blog.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True)
Blog.objects.in_bulk(blog_query)
```

Comment: Doesn't this make two DB hits?